# Defining a type only by its inheritance from other classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I am implementing a visual tree in SFML. SFML contains two important drawing classes: `sf::Drawable` and `sf::Transformable`. It would be nice if these were bundled up together, but they are not. Many objects inherit from both, i.e.:

```
class SFML_GRAPHICS_API Text : public Drawable, public Transformable

class SFML_GRAPHICS_API Sprite : public Drawable, public Transformable

class SFML_GRAPHICS_API Shape : public Drawable, public Transformable
```

For my visual tree, I have a `SceneNode` class that inherits from Drawable and Transformable, and a draw function will call a private onDraw itself, and then its children. However, many SFML native classes, such as `sf::Text`, have a draw function that is private. So, I cannot create a class like

```
class Text: public sf::Text, public SceneNode
```

and then put it into the visual tree. For these native classes, I don't need them to have draw children anyway, I just want to be able to add them to the visual tree as leaf nodes. The crux of the problem is that each member of the visual tree needs to inherit from `sf::Drawable` and `sf::Tranformable`. I need to be able to define a type that inherits from both of these. If I define the dummy class

```
class LeafNode: public sf::Drawable, public sf::Tranformable { }
```

which appears to define the type I want. Then, `SceneNode` will contain `std::vector<LeafNode*> m_children`. When drawing these children, I will do a dynamic cast on each item to see if it is a `SceneNode`, and then call a draw function so the `SceneNode` draws its children.

However the following code does not compile due to type incompatibility:

```
LeafNode * node = new sf::Text("PLAY", font, 20);
```

Ideally, I want to define something like

```
std::vector<sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable*> m_children
```

Where that made-up syntax means that each element must derive from both `sf::Drawable` and `sf::Transformable`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> However, many SFML native classes, such as sf::Text, have a draw function that is private

That's not quite true. Since the `sf::Drawable::draw` function is protected, so is the `draw` method of `sf::Text`. It's one of the complex rules of C++.

> So, I cannot create a class like
>
> ```
> class Text: public sf::Text, public SceneNode
> ```

If you did you would have two `sf::Drawable` and `sf::Transformable` base classes in your hierarchy, one from `sf::Text` and one from `SceneNode`. That wouldn't be good.

> When drawing these children, I will do a dynamic cast on each item to see if it is a SceneNode, and then call a draw function so the SceneNode draws its children.

I would not recommend such design. Using dynamic_cast is usually a sign your software design is not so great. (I don't want to digress too much on this topic, google about that topic.)

But let's answer your fundamental question:

> Where that made-up syntax means that each element must derive from both sf::Drawable and sf::Transformable. Is this possible?

No. But you can do simpler things anyway.

Instead of having `Text` inheriting from both `sf::Text` and `SceneNode`, define you class as a wrapper. It can be as simple as:

```
class Text : public SceneNode {
    sf::Text m_text;
public:
    sf::Text& get() { return m_text; }

    // Override SceneNode drawing method:
    virtual void onDraw(RenderTarget& target) const
        // Draw m_text:
        target.draw(m_text);
    }
};
```

There is two flaws with this quick wrapper, though. a) It doesn't use the transformable part of the `SceneNode`. b) Since the encapsulation is broken with `get()` there are two transformable modifiable by the user: the one from `SceneNode` and the one of `sf::Text`.

For a), the fix should be straightforward when you have fixed b). To fix b), you have to make the wrapper a little bit more complex: instead of having this ugly `get()`, write methods to set the properties of the underlying `sf::Text` that are not linked to `sf::Transformable`, e.g. `setColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about SMFL (which may provide better solutions) I think you can implement this vector. You only need to define your own pointer wrapper, which only accepts pointers to objects which inherits from more than one type:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct special_pointer_wrapper
{
    T1* t1;
    T2* t2;
    template<class T>
    special_pointer_wrapper(T* p)
        : t1(dynamic_cast<T1*>(p))
        , t2(dynamic_cast<T2*>(p))
    {
       if ((p1==0) || (p2==0))
           throw "Error";
    }

    getT1 T1* () const { return t1; }
    getT2 T2* () const { return t2; }
};
```

This class takes any pointer and ensures its pointed to type is derived from T1 and T2 (even if they seem to be totally unrelated). If its not a derived object it throws. With functions `getT1()` and `getT2()` it gives you access to pointers to both base classes.

Please note the construction may be slow due `dynamic_cast` but extraction of the types is O(1).